# Pointlessly trying to compare rsp across a call without using registers

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, thunk

I would like to write a small thunk which will call an underlying function and then compare the value of `rsp` before and after the call. Critically, this code shouldn't clobber any registers.

The obvious implementation is to simply `push rsp` before the call, and then compare after. The problem is that `push rsp` itself subtracts 8 from the stack, so you should actually compare the saved value of `rsp` with the value after the call *plus 8*.

Here's one way to do it:

```
foo_thunk:
push rsp              ; save the value of rsp
call foo              ; call the underlying function
add rsp, 8            ; adjust rsp by 8, popping the saved value
cmp rsp, [rsp - 8]    
jne bad_rsp           ; bad foo!
ret
```

The problem is this accesses a value `[rsp - 8]` which is above `rsp` - i.e., not *on* the stack but the nebulous region *above* the stack. This should be where you have a red-zone, but it isn't when you don't.

What are the alternatives? Performance and code-size is important.

Comment: Does it have to be re-entrant?

Comment: Also that breaks alignment requirement. You are of course not required to adjust `rsp` before the comparison so you don't need to access under the stack pointer. Worse problem is, there may be arguments on the stack that you need to handle.

Comment: @harold - yes it does.

Comment: PS: if `rsp` is destroyed chances are the `foo` will not return to you so I don't see much point in checking. XY problem?

Comment: @Jester - good point, fixed (I think).

Comment: @Jester - yes, most of the time you are right, and this check won't fire. Still I would like to know how to write it.

Comment: Jester is also correct about this throwing functions with enough parameters  out of whack if they are spilled to the stack.

Comment: You can allocate a separate stack for the values.

Comment: @Jester Separate space for the values would be my method.

Comment: Another alternative: `sub rsp,8` `push verify_rsp_is_valid` `call foo_with_no_args_in_stack` `ret` `verify_rsp_is_valid: add rsp,8` `ret`. Will continue correctly only when `rsp` was valid, or the `foo` understands your trickery and jumps directly or leaves `verify_rsp_is_valid` address in stack on proper place. In case of bad `rsp` you will end randomly elsewhere. But that's the same thing as ordinary `foo` will do either way, so the practical usability looks to be close to zero, I would rather understand some canary system to check for stack overwriting, then checking the `rsp` itself.

Comment: Right @Ped7g - but this is separate from stack overwriting: it's checking that `rsp` is properly handled (but it's not going to work). Canary is checking for overwriting (and like this check also is best in the `callee` since it's not going to work in a thunk).

Comment: @Ped7g : That still would screw up any function call where there are enough parameters where they get spilled to the stack.

Comment: @MichaelPetch sure.. that's why I called it `foo_with_no_args_in_stack` ... but overall it's simply very stupid alternative, thinking about it. Also even if it is transparent no-op for ordinary code, it's huge "welcome here" attack vector for any malicious code, so I would definitely not suggest to use something like that. As long as I am concerned, if the `call foo` will later reach the next instruction, it means the `rsp` is by 99.99% correct one, or you are under heavy attack. Another alternative is probably self-mod to store `rsp` as immediate for `cmp`, but `cmp rsp,imm64` is not valid??

Comment: And self-mod in such near vicinity may have performance implications, so from performance perspective it's probably better to store/restore other registers, and spill the test code mechanism over those with separate stack for the rsp check values.  (I'm more like thinking loudly, because I believe BeeOnRope is experienced enough to pick up only signal and ignore the noise) .. just as catch prog. errors even `cmp esp,imm32` may be enough!

Comment: Just to provide some motivation: this was a sub-question of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905229/writing-a-thunk-to-verify-sysv-abi-compliance) which is intended to be a fail-fast check for the C-asm interface (or asm-asm interface) in "debug" mode (i.e., it can be disabled with a compile-time variable). I've debugged too many heisenbugs where some callee-preserved register was clobbered (or worse: _sometimes_ clobbered) which broke (or not) the calling code in wonderful ways depending on compiler flags, etc. This idea of checking `rsp` in the thunk seems DOA though.

Comment: @Jester - actually I think the alignment of the original code was correct. As I understand it, the caller must have a 16B aligned stack at the moment of the call, which means it is misaligned again by 8B in the callee since the `call` pushes the return address. So the `sub rsp, 8` aligns it again.

Comment: @BeeOnRope yeah my bad, sorry!

Comment: @Jester - well your genius separate stacks idea is the special sauce I needed all along so in the end this apparently pointless question was well-worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a simple solution is just to use `sub` and `mov` to adjust the stack, rather than `push`:

```
foo_thunk:
sub rsp, 8            ; 16 to maintain alignment
mov [rsp], rsp        ; save the value of rsp
call foo              ; call the underlying function
cmp rsp, [rsp]    
jne bad_rsp           ; bad foo!
add rsp, 8            ; pop the stack
ret
```

Of course, if the callee `foo` messed up the stack pointer, it probably [won't return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920969/comparing-rsp-across-a-call-without-using-registers?noredirect=1#comment80789516_46920969) to the calling thunk at all, so this check has limited usefulness. It would be better off in the callee as a check prior to `ret`.

The the original caller has put any arguments on the stack you are [really screwed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920969/comparing-rsp-across-a-call-without-using-registers/46921045#comment80789470_46920969). Putting the check in the `callee` solves that too.

Comment: It *could* change `rsp`, still return, and also pass that test though

Comment: @harold - you mean by also overwriting the saved value of `rsp` on the stack? Sure. To be clear my motivation here is to catch programming errors quickly, not as a mechanism to defend against malicious code. Of course, it still fails in that approach because a function that fails to maintain `rsp` properly is almost never going to return to the thunk as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: You'll want to change the sub and add to use 8 instead of 16 to match the conclusion reached in the comments to the question.

Comment: @BeeOnRope:  It's possible for `foo` to pop the return address, make a stack frame somewhere else, and `ret` there.  But passing this test doesn't involve *overwriting* anything, it involves making a value at the new location point to itself.  Your check is using the new `rsp`.  This kind of mistake is very unlikely to happen by accident; I wouldn't worry about it.  (Fun fact: gcc will sometimes copy a stack frame including return address, although it doesn't use it to return.  Just to have a stack frame for backtraces or something I think.  I forget why, maybe GNU C nested functions.)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed from the original question that you wanted to adjust rsp by 8 *before* branching to bad_rsp when there is an error, which you can do with

```
foo_thunk:
    sub rsp, 8
    mov [rsp], rsp
    call foo
    cmp rsp, [rsp]
    lea rsp, [rsp+8]
    jne bad_rsp
    ret
```

(Of course, once you've determined rsp has not been preserved, there's probably no need to adjust it, but I think this approach is useful enough to be worth mentioning.)

Comment: Also possible: `pop rsp` instead of `lea`, except that if RSP isn't pointing to your saved RSP anymore, you're screwed a different way.  (And `pop rsp` is 3 uops on IvyBridge and later, slower than `lea`).

Answer (score -2):

Self mod alternative, checking only low 32b part of `rsp`:

```
foo_thunk:
mov [cs:check_esp_part+2],esp
call foo              ; call the underlying function
check_esp_part:
cmp esp,0x12345678
jne bad_rsp           ; bad foo!
ret
```

Comment: In 64 bit mode you can just write the value into nearby memory and use `cmp rsp, [rip+x]`. Logically this is just a global variable (and due to non-writable code page probably a non working one ;)) and definitely not reentrant.

Comment: @Jester forgot about re-entrant constraint. The addressing + access are more like implementation detail ;), but reentrant makes this plain wrong and useless.

Comment: If you're doing this for hardening purposes, this requires a memory page with write+exec permissions (for self-modifying code).  Normally you wouldn't need that.